# UBER CRM case study Customer retention metrics in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

**Background**: I want to find the retention of a customer cohort on a
weekly-rolling basis, so that they can take necessary intervention if a rider has not taken a ride for 28 days.

Link : [Problem in detail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dmvDn1nfk3cmdqeGtvaTczbVI4YmdVVU54S0diQXN4TVU4/view?usp=sharing)

**Below are list of metrics I'm trying to achieve in a single query**

Definitions of Columns in the Output Query (Single Query):

1. date: the date in respect to which the below metric will be computed.
2. city_id: the id of the city
3. dau: Count of distinct riders who have completed min one trip on that date.
4. wau: Count of distinct riders who have completed min **one trip** in the last 7 days with respect to the date in column ‘date’
5. new_rider: count of distinct riders who have taken their `first trip` in the last 7 days with respect to the date in column ‘date’
6. previous_mau: count of distinct riders who have taken min one trip between the last 56 to last 29 days with respect to the date in column ‘date’
7. mau_28: Count of distinct riders who have completed min one trip in the last 28 days with respect to the date in column ‘date’
8. retained: intersection of distinct riders in the previous_mau and mau_28 phase
9. resurrect: count of distinct riders who were inactive in the previous_mau phase but were active in the mau_28 phase.
10. churn: count of riders who were active in the previous_mau phase but inactive in the
    mau_28 phase.

*Active : If a rider has completed at least one trip in the respective period
Inactive : If a rider has not taken a single trip in the respective period*

Below is what I have tried:

```
create table Tripdata
(
  [date] date,
  rider_id int,
  trip_id int,
  city_id int,
  status varchar(100)
)
go
```

**Query  to insert values**

```
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 348, 1, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1729, 2, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5265, 3, 4, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2098, 4, 4, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4942, 5, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5424, 6, 11, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4269, 7, 7, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5649, 8, 1, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2385, 9, 6, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5161, 10, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 571, 11, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5072, 12, 9, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1233, 13, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2490, 14, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5665, 15, 9, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1400, 16, 2, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3324, 17, 4, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2533, 18, 13, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5314, 19, 11, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4773, 20, 12, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5544, 21, 2, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tripdata] ([datee], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1232, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
```

Below is what I got/Acheived so far: (Credit goes to [LukStorms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003419/lukstorms))

```
   SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  [datee], city_id, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT rider_id) AS [dau]
        FROM [dbo].[Tripdata]
        GROUP BY [datee], city_id
    ) t
    OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT
       COUNT(rider_id) AS [wau],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [rides]=1 THEN rider_id END) AS [new_rider]
       FROM
       (
          SELECT t2.city_id, t2.rider_id,
           COUNT(*) AS [rides]
          FROM [dbo].[Tripdata] t2
          WHERE t2.city_id = t.city_id
            AND t2.[datee] <= t.[datee]
          AND t2.[datee]>=dateadd(day,-7,t.[datee])
          GROUP BY t2.city_id, t2.rider_id
       ) q
       GROUP BY city_id
    ) last7
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT t2.rider_id) AS [previous_mau]
        FROM [dbo].[Tripdata] t2
        WHERE t2.city_id = t.city_id
          AND t2.[datee] <= dateadd(day,-29,t.[datee])
          AND t2.[datee] >= dateadd(day,-56,t.[datee])
    ) prev29

    ORDER BY t.[datee], t.city_id;
```

How to achieve all the results of the above queries in a single query? And how to write a query to answer 7,8,9,10 questions above in a single query output?

also, they are few special considerations for mapping rider to a particular city

A rider may take a trip from multiple cities, which might lead to counting the riders active
or inactive in multiple cities. Hence to solve this problem a rider needs to be mapped to
one city only. A rider should be mapped to a city from which they have taken the
maximum trips considering only their recent 20 trips.
2. For all calculations related to a city it is important to consider the city mapped to a rider
instead of the city where the trip occurred.
3. Our database system does not have a standard mode function so the rider city mapping
needs to be derived.

Comment: Can you show the expected results for the given sample data.

Comment: Hi Dale K, I have hyperlinked the detailed document of what I’m trying to achieve by this query

Comment: SO questions need to be stand-alone and not depend on external resources.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it ->

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/092aa/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table TripData
(
  [date] date,
  rider_id int,
  trip_id int,
  city_id int,
  status varchar(100)
)
go
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 348, 1, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1729, 2, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5265, 3, 4, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2098, 4, 4, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4942, 5, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5424, 6, 11, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4269, 7, 7, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5649, 8, 1, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2385, 9, 6, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5161, 10, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 571, 11, 8, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5072, 12, 9, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1233, 13, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2490, 14, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5665, 15, 9, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1400, 16, 2, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3324, 17, 4, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2533, 18, 13, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5314, 19, 11, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4773, 20, 12, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5544, 21, 2, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1232, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 111, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 111, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 111, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-03-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 111, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 111, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-15T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 222, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 222, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 333, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 333, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-15T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 222, 22, 10, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 222, 22, 10, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 333, 22, 10, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 333, 22, 10, N'completed')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3333, 22, 10, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3333, 22, 10, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-06-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1112, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1112, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-05-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1112, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-03-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1112, 22, 5, N'completed')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TripData] ([date], [rider_id], [trip_id], [city_id], [status]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-01-28T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1112, 22, 5, N'completed')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH AdddedIndicators AS
(
   /*For every record, calculate the key metrics needed to aggerate up.
     days_back_last_ride can make use of LAG() by rider and city ordered by date or null if no value,
     ISNULL the result to bring it back to 0 meaning no days back(first ride).
     Days_back_last_ride=0 could be used to determine first ride date, however, that would ot fit the between 1..7 rule
     so we need a first_ride_date. Again, using a window function by rider and city, grab the min date*/
   SELECT 
      td.date, rider_id, city_id,
      days_back_last_ride = ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(date) OVER(PARTITION BY rider_id,city_id ORDER BY date),td.date),0),
      first_ride_date =  MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY rider_id, city_id)
  FROM    
      TripData td
  )
,Normalized AS
(
    /*The need metrics have been calculated above  for the bulk of your calcs with the data, query it and 
    build up, aggregates up, flags for each rider/city/date so we can ultimatley formulate this for each rider/city
    since this is by rider, city and date the user will allocate points to every city
    vistited in a given day*/
    SELECT 
        date, city_id, rider_id,
        dau= COUNT(DISTINCT rider_id),
        wau_flag = SUM(CASE WHEN  days_back_last_ride BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        new_rider_flag = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,first_ride_date,date) <= 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        previous_mau_flag = SUM(CASE WHEN  days_back_last_ride BETWEEN 29 AND 56 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        mau_28_flag = SUM(CASE WHEN days_back_last_ride BETWEEN 1 AND 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        retained = CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN days_back_last_ride BETWEEN 1 AND 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 
                   AND   
                   SUM(CASE WHEN  days_back_last_ride BETWEEN 29 AND 56 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM 
        AdddedIndicators
    GROUP BY
        city_id, date, rider_id
)
SELECT 
    /* Finalize the results by date and city
    The flags have been made by user, city and date above. 
    So gather each data piont and sum them up based on the rule set */
    date, city_id,
    dau = SUM(dau),
    wau_flag = SUM(CASE WHEN wau_flag  >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    retained = SUM(CASE WHEN previous_mau_flag >= 1 AND mau_28_flag >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    resurrect = SUM(CASE WHEN previous_mau_flag = 0 AND mau_28_flag >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    churn  = SUM(CASE WHEN previous_mau_flag >= 1 AND mau_28_flag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    Normalized
GROUP BY
    date, city_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/092aa/4/0)**:

```
|       date | city_id | dau | wau_flag | retained | resurrect | churn |
|------------|---------|-----|----------|----------|-----------|-------|
| 2019-06-01 |       1 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |       2 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |       4 |   3 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-01-28 |       5 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-03-28 |       5 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-05-01 |       5 |   3 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     2 |
| 2019-05-15 |       5 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-05-28 |       5 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         2 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |       5 |   8 |        2 |        0 |         3 |     1 |
| 2019-06-01 |       6 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |       7 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |       8 |   4 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |       9 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-05-01 |      10 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-05-15 |      10 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |      10 |   3 |        0 |        0 |         1 |     2 |
| 2019-06-01 |      11 |   2 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |      12 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
| 2019-06-01 |      13 |   1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |     0 |
```

Comment: I missed the requirements to roll up the results by city and date, instead of date and that bit was added. Also the dau was added. I didn't have time to unwind and properly test but I think the results are sound.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select [date], city_id
,(select count(distinct [rider_id])  from #Tripdata b where b.[date] = a.[date] and a.city_id = b.city_id) as [dau]
,(select count(distinct [rider_id])  from #Tripdata b where b.[date] between dateadd(day, -7, a.[date]) and a.[date] and a.city_id = b.city_id) as [wau]

,(select count(distinct [rider_id])  from #Tripdata b where a.city_id = b.city_id 
    and b.[rider_id] NOT IN  (Select c.[rider_id] from #Tripdata c where c.[date] < dateadd(day, -7, a.[date])) 
    and b.[rider_id] NOT IN  (Select c.[rider_id] from #Tripdata c where c.[date] > a.[date]) 
) as [new_rider]

,(select count(distinct [rider_id])  from #Tripdata b where a.city_id = b.city_id 
    and b.[rider_id] NOT IN  (Select c.[rider_id] from #Tripdata c where c.[date] < dateadd(day, -56, a.[date])) 
    and b.[rider_id] NOT IN  (Select c.[rider_id] from #Tripdata c where c.[date] > dateadd(day, -29, a.[date])) 
) as [previous_mau]

from #Tripdata a
group by  [date], city_id
```